# Is it safe calling database information from Next-Auth session callback

Tags: mongodb, session, next.js, session-cookies, next-auth

```
 callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token and user id from a provider.
     const getUserEmail = session.user.email;
      const userData = await User.findOne({ email: getUserEmail }).select('-password');
      session.user = userData
      return session
    }
```

I have this code from Next-Auth CredentialsProvider provider, is this approach safe to apply? Because session information only contains email but nothing else. I should have take all the mongodb information to use users profile, name, image  etc. What do you say?

Answer (score -3):

In security, it's better that you make yourself code. Using other libs may cause security problems.

Making a lib to have a secure auth is so easy. You just work with `JWT` and have a secure `JWT-SECRET-KEY`. That is all!

I write useful libs to make a secure auth in nextjs:

1. To use sign and decode JWT: [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)
2. To decode session (JWT) in client without using secret key. This will help you to decode safely in client. Because you not pass secret key. You can use this option just for something easy like profile name and so. [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode)
3. To make secure `JWT-SECRET-KEY` in Linux use this code in terminal:

`openssl rand -base64 60`

4. To save the token as cookie use these libs. I used many libs but they not work correctly: (Recommended) -> [cookies-next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next) and if you don't like it use [nookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies)
5. (Optional): And if you want to save the JWT session in DB that is NOT necessary if your secret-key is secure, you can use this ORM: [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/)

Comment: What kind of problems Next-Auth has? Why we shouldn't use this library?

Comment: I used Next-Auth from v3 to v4. All of the versions have API problems that cause server side errors all the time. Also storing all sessions and other data in DB is not necessary! And last advice, always use private lib for security options.

Comment: If you think this is the answer, please submit it. Thanks